# turn a string variable containing dates into a date variable Stata

Tags: stata

I have  variables day,month and year, month is string and day,year is numeric, what is the fastest way to convert this into the correct date format (dmy)? I know I can write code converting the month into numeric month (might be little long) and then use mdy() function, is there a faster way ? or make use of the original month and year to create a mdy format?

I appreciate any suggestion

Comment: I guess the downvotes reflect one or more (1) no attempt at code (2) no data example to use in answers (3) this is a beginner question as basic functions suffice. (Don't shoot the messenger.)

Comment: Well, I am new to stata. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider concatenating variables (converting numeric ones to string) and then converting to `DMY`:

Input Data

```
month     day   year
January   21    2016
February  13    2016
March     6     2016
```

Stata script

```
gen fulldate = date(string(day) + "" + month + "" + string(year), "DMY")
format fulldate %td
```

Result

```
month       day year    fulldate
January     21  2016    21jan2016
February    13  2016    13feb2016
March       6   2016    06mar2016
```